# FCMPlugin is not Defined in home.ts

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I am trying to send a Push notification Using Firebase and Ionic 3. I have already imported the FCMPlugin in my project though my cmd. When I am creating a new message in firebase and try tos end, I don't receive anything, I run console log in my project and it gives me the following error "FCMPlugin is not defined".

I have declared the Plugin in my home.ts, but I am still getting this error, my home.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
declare var FCMPlugin: any; // <---- this is the magic line

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private alert:AlertController, private platform:Platform) {
this.onNotification();
  }


 async  onNotification(){

try {

await this.platform.ready();
 FCMPlugin.onNotification((data)=>{

    this.alert.create({


   message: data.message

    }).present(); 

},(error) => console.error(error));
}
catch (e) {
console.error(e);

}

 }

}
```

Can anyone provide me some guidance asIi am quite new to ionic? 
Thanks in Regards

Comment: are you trying this in an emulator or a device

Answer (score 0):

try using the FCM onNotification method inside an if block so that whenever you use it on a browser or whenever FCM is called before its initialisation it will not throw an error:

```
if (typeof FCMPlugin != 'undefined') {
  FCMPlugin.onNotification((data)=>{})
}
```